# Помоготите разобрать с простым примером asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, async-await, asyncio

Не могу понять в чём тут ошибка. Помоготите разобрать

```
import asyncio

async def my_coro():
    while True:
        print("Blocking...")
        await asyncio.sleep(1.0)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(my_coro()))
loop.close
```

Использую python3.6 asyncio (3.4.3)

При выполнении программы выдаётся вот такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test2.py", line 14, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(my_coro()))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 484, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 302, in wait
    raise TypeError("expect a list of futures, not %s" % type(fs).__name__)
TypeError: expect a list of futures, not coroutine
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'my_coro' was never awaited
```

Comment: Ну так в тексте ошибки всё написано: asyncio.wait ожидает **список** корутин, а вы скормили ему **одну** корутину без всякого списка

Comment: И вообще зачем вас asyncio.wait, что мешает сделать просто `loop.run_until_complete(my_coro())` ?

Comment: @andreymal т.е. такая конструкция ```loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(my_coro()))``` предназначена для запуска сразу несколько карутин? Спасибо большое.